# Image alt not showing at magento product page

Tags: magento-1.9, php

Image Alt not showing at magento product page

```
<img class="imgbox" src="http://shop.example.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/357x368/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/v/o/vogel_1.jpg" alt="" title="Optional title display" style="display: block;">
```

This what i see.. and this the view phtml:

```
<?php
/** Magento NOTICE OF LICENSE [...] DISCLAIMER [...] */
/**
 * Product view template
 *
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View
 * @see Mage_Review_Block_Product_View
 */
?>
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
</script>
<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?></div>
<div class="product-view">
    <div class="product-essential">
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
        <div class="no-display">
            <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
        </div>

        <div class="product-img-box">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>
        </div>

        <div class="product-shop">
            <div class="product-name">
                <h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
            </div>

        <?php if ($this->canEmailToFriend()): ?>
                <p class="email-friend"><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product')->getEmailToFriendUrl($_product) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Email to a Friend') ?></a></p>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, false, true)?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>

            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>

            <?php if (!$this->hasOptions()):?>
                <div class="add-to-box">
                    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
                        <?php if( $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() || $_compareUrl=$this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product)): ?>
                            <span class="or"><?php echo $this->__('OR') ?></span>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                </div>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_buttons') ?>
            <?php elseif (!$_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                <div class="add-to-box">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
                <!--<div class="short-description">
                    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Quick Overview') ?></h2>
                    <div class="std"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>
                </div>-->
            <?php endif;?>

            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('other');?>

            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
            <?php endif;?>


            <div class="clearer"></div>
            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
            <?php endif;?>
        </div>

        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('product_static')->toHtml() ?>

    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
        productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                var form = this.form;
                var oldUrl = form.action;

                if (url) {
                   form.action = url;
                }
                var e = null;
                try {
                    this.form.submit();
                } catch (e) {
                }
                this.form.action = oldUrl;
                if (e) {
                    throw e;
                }

                if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                    button.disabled = true;
                }
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

        productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
            if(this.validator) {
                var nv = Validation.methods;
                delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
                // Remove custom datetime validators
                for (var methodName in Validation.methods) {
                    if (methodName.match(/^validate-datetime-.*/i)) {
                        delete Validation.methods[methodName];
                    }
                }

                if (this.validator.validate()) {
                    if (url) {
                        this.form.action = url;
                    }
                    this.form.submit();
                }
                Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
    //]]>
    </script>
    </div>

    <div class="product-collateral">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('info_tabs') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data') ?>

    </div>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('related_products') ?>
</div>
```

so i'm not sure how to make it show the image alt.

EDIT ( This what i have in the media.phtml )

```
<p class="product-image product-image-zoom">
    <?php
        $_img = '<img id="image" src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image').'" alt="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'" title="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'" />';
        echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_img, 'image');
    ?>
</p>
```

Comment: the images are located in the `catalog/product/view/media.phtml` or another in case you have some kind of zoom extension

Answer (score 1):

The image label is stored in the catalog flat table so you will need to make sure you have indexed your products if you have flat catalog turned on.

Answer (score 0):

Check you theme's media.phtml file for following code

```
<p class="product-image product-image-zoom">
    <?php
        $_img = '<img id="image" src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image').'" alt="'.$this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()).'" title="'.$this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()).'" />';
        echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_img, 'image');
    ?>
</p>
```

Check if you have `alt="'.$this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel())` in your code or not

Check if any other module is overriding the media.phtml file or not?

Comment: I've this already.. and it's not working